# Function import from another file based on packaging (setup.py) leads to "No .egg-info directory found"

Tags: python, pip, python-import, setup.py, python-packaging

My goal is to access a function called train_test_split(...) from the file utils.py within dnn.py. My structure is the following:

```
├───MachineLearning
│   └───src
│       ├───deep_learning
|           └─── dnn.py
|           └─── __init__.py
│       └───utils
|           └─── preprocessing.py
|           └─── __init__.py
│   └───readme.md
│   └───setup.py
```

I don't want to use or change my windows path because it should run on other computers too that clone from my github. The solution I found is using a setup.py file. I spent a really long time trying to understand how it works and ended up with the structure above.
My setup.py file contains this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='example',
    version='0.1.0',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Now when I run `pip install -e .` from the the root folder (MachineLearning) I get the following error:

```
(tf38_clone) F:\Code\MachineLearning>pip install -e .          
Obtaining file:///F:/Code/MachineLearning
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-pvq_am4y
```

Can anybody point me into the right direction? The only thing I want is to import my function into another .py file as described above.

Answer (score 0):

If your

> goal is to access a function called train_test_split(...) from the file utils.py within dnn.py

which you also indicated by writing

> The only thing I want is to import my function into another .py file as described above.

then you should try `from utils import train_test_split` at the beginning your `dnn.py` to import the function from the other module. There is no need for creating a package for this use case. More information about modules in python can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

However, if you want to install an editable package, you need to build one first (i.e., `python -m build`), which will create `*.egg-info` in your stacktrace. You can read more about packaging [here](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, Marcel!
I get this error when I use 'from utils import train_test_split' :
'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils''
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried adding an  `__init__.py` to `src`? I think this is required as it is part of your module hierarchy. Let me know if it does not work.